# Get second attribute with Beautiful Soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've got this html and a series of images to get with this structure:

```
<portrait a>
 <img class = "image" data = "random stuff" src = "image_link">
<portrait b>
 <img class = "image" data = "random stuff" src = "image_link">
```

I want to get the image_link. I've tryed this but it didn't work. I don't understand how to get the second attribute with get().

```
i = d.find_all("img", class_ = "image")
for item in i:
    img = item.get("src")
    print(img)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this `d.find("img", class_= "image").get("src")`.

Comment: But I've got more than one image to get. I'll correct the question

Comment: Are you sure that required images present in page source?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlcontent = """
<portrait a>
 <img class = "image" data = "random stuff" src = "image_link1">
<portrait b>
 <img class = "image" data = "random stuff" src = "image_link2">
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all("img",class_="image"):
    print(item.get("src"))
```

Output:

```
image_link1
image_link2
```

Comment: I don't know why but i get "None" as a result

Comment: Are you sure the content you are trying to fetch are not dynamically generated? If the answer is yes then you need any browser simulator to fetch the content.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not. But there's a ::before before (pun unintended) <portrait>: